# Load data into ModelForm fields in edit mode before it rendered

Tags: django, modelform

I have a field in ModelForm that does not exist in model. The field is saved separately by overriding ModelForm.save() function:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    custom_field = CharField(label='Custom field', widget=TextInput())
    def save(self, commit=True):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        # save custom_field
```

Now how can I load this custom field into the ModelForm (in edit mode) before it rendered. I tried to set the fields dictionary but the field dictionary does not exist in ModelForm:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['custom_field'] = self.instance._meta.model.custom_field
```

I get the following error:

```
type object 'MyForm' has no attribute 'fields'
```

Comment: can u show your form fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide the initial data for the field use the `initial` parameter:

```
form = MyForm(instance=my_obj, initial={'custom_field': 'Test'})
```

Or, if you want to do it in the `__init__` constructor:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['initial'] = kwargs.get('initial', {})
    kwargs['initial']['custom_field'] = 'Test'
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you @catavaran. This does not work, because 'initial' key only used when the form is in INSERT mode. When the form is in EDIT mode, the initial key does not exist.

Comment: It perfectly works in EDIT mode.  Just pass the `initial` alongside with the `instance` argument.  See the updated example in my answer.

Comment: You are right @catavaran. It seems to works. Do you have any idea how I can access the model of the current edited form?

Comment: You can get the model from the instance's `_meta` attribute: `form.instance._meta.model`

Comment: The problem with `instance` is that it is not accessible before calling super. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: `kwargs.get('instance')` will return the instance object or `None` if the instance is not passed.